# How to get a Blob size? (Python Google App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blob

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#Blob

Comment: If the link is the answer, could you also write the answer in your post as well so that those of us looking this up don't have to click through?

Comment: The link is not the answer, it's just a link to all documentation about this class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{ theblob|length }}` if you're using a Django template (as you seem to indicate in a comment, although you give absolutely no indication of this in your question -- I suggest editing the question to add that crucial bit of info!-).

Comment: Yeah, so its `len( theblob )` essentially

Comment: Yes, the `length` filter in Django templates does perform the equivalent of what `len` would do in Python code.

Answer (score -1):

Try `blob.getSize()`

Comment: Is not working inside the template.
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse some characters: file.content.getSize|()||escape

Comment: Don't put () brackets to call the function from the template (`blob.getSize`).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039422/django-template-call-function/2039459#2039459