# Django template call function

Tags: django, google-app-engine, templates

Using Google App Engine and Django.

Whenever I have a `db.ReferenceProperty()` inside a model like:

```
class User( db.Model ) :
    name = db.StringProperty()
    avatar = db.ReferenceProperty( dbImage )
```

So when putting out a User's page, in the Django template I can't do:

```
<div>
    <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
    <span>{{ user.avatar.key() }}</span>
</div>
```

What I'm doing right now is writing a bit of Python code before the data goes out to the template that looks like:

```
user.avatarsKey = user.avatar.key()
```

Then

```
<div>
    <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
    <span>{{ user.avatarsKey }}</span>
</div>
```

eliminating the function call.  I don't like this though, because I have to do it in a lot of places and it's starting to get cluttery.  Is there a way to invoke the `.key()` method of a DB object from inside the template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In django templates, function invocation is just function getting. in your example, try:

```
{{ user.avatar.key }}
```

I know, it's weird. But hey, it's even worse with arrays/lists:

```
{{ user.mylist.0 }}
```

Comment: Remarkably this works even when the `avatar` object is None.  It doesn't throw a NoneType error or anything like that.  Amazing.

Comment: Yeah, django templates don't throw errors. That bothers me, so I normally use genshi for any reasonably large project. The philosophy is, you don't want a damn know-nothing designer to crash your sight. Agree or disagree as you may.

Comment: So, you can't send arguments to a function from a django template,

Comment: Not as far as I know. Again, I dislike the django template engine, and it's not hard at all to replace it with something sane, like Genshi.